# How to notify outside thread of main thread state without using global variables?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, state, program-entry-point

Say i have main thread and it is running my win32 procedure and a few worker threads to carry out functions that are clicked on by the user.

Lets say there is a change in the main function (I want 1 button to be available while another one is not, but only when the program enters a certain state (i.e by a boolean trigger or something of that nature), and notify all running threads that i want to disable to terminate?)?

Passing arguments to the thread only captures the state of the main thread at a certain point in time. What if i want to monitor the state of my main thread across different time frames or events?

I currently have a few global boolean values to flag/signal the program's current mode or state and that is how i notify the worker threads in how they should change their behavior.

Should I eliminate my use of global variables or keep them? Or if i should eliminate the global varialbes, how would i reimplement my program?

Comment: You can always set up a message loop and use `PostThreadMessage`.

Comment: Global variables are sometimes the least troublesome option.

Comment: True i can always setup my own customized messages and use postthreadmessage. That is quite a good idea since my threads will run in infinite loops anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still pass arguments to your worker thread at construction time. But do not pass it *copies* of your state variables (because as you said, they "only captures the state of the main thread at a certain point in time", which is the worker thread creation time).

Instead, pass it *pointers* (or references) to your state variables.

Because they are pointers, your worker thread will have access to the latest data from the main thread without the need to use globals.

Below is a pseudo-code example (without any synchronization mechanism, like mutex):

```
DWORD MyThreadFunction( LPVOID argument );

int main()
{
    bool mySyncVar = false;
    bool* mySyncVarPtr = &mySyncVar;

    CreateThread( 
        NULL,               // default security attributes
        0,                  // use default stack size  
        MyThreadFunction,   // thread function name
        mySyncVarPtr,       // argument to thread function--NOTE THAT THIS IS
                            // A POINTER TO THE SYNC VARIABLE 
        0,                  // use default creation flags 
        NULL);              // returns the thread identifier 

    for (...)
    {
        // Do stuffs
        mySyncVar = true; // Will trigger worker thread
        // ...
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD MyThreadFunction( LPVOID argument )
{
    bool* syncPtr = reinterpret_cast<bool*>(argument); // Remember this
                                                       // is a pointer
    for (...)
    {
        while (false == *syncPtr)
        {
            // Wait...
        }
        // Trigger
        // Update your buttons now
    }
}
```